# RecyclerView doesn't update the UI after data changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new in android development, after make a network request trying to update item view in the `RecyclerView` control without scrolling it. As far as I understand items gets refreshed during scroll via `onBindViewHolder` event.here is the code. Using `notifyItemChanged` method to update UI but it doesn't work until user scroll.

Note : `favoriteMatches` is not my data source. It is another list of objects which stores user favorites,
inside `onBindViewHolder` event I am cheking if item is `favoriteMatches.contains(match)` then render as fav item.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<AddRemoveFavoriteRequest.Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AddRemoveFavoriteRequest.Response> call, Response<AddRemoveFavoriteRequest.Response> response) {
            AddRemoveFavoriteRequest.Response body = response.body();
            Utilities.dismissProgressDialog(getActivity(),progressBar);

            if(body.error == null){
                if(add){
                    favoriteMatches.add(matchId);
                }
                else {
                    favoriteMatches.remove(matchId);
                }

                adapter.notifyItemChanged(absolutePosition);
                Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                        .putStringSet(Preferences.PREF_FAVORITES,favoriteMatches)
                        .apply();

            }else{
                Utilities.showSnackBar(getActivity(),recyclerView,body.error);
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<AddRemoveFavoriteRequest.Response> call, Throwable t) {
             t.printStackTrace();
             Utilities.dismissProgressDialog(getActivity(),progressBar);

        }
});
```

Comment: What is `absolutePosition`?

Comment: Try using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, if that does not work, then your problem is in your data. If it works, then check if `absolutePosition` is correct.

Comment: @cricket_007 the absolutePosition is the position of item in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyItemChanged` takes the position at which the item changed.

You are adding and removing elements, so that position is going to move around. Instead, you can individually notify at positions.

```
int changedPosition = 0;
if(add){
    changedPosition = favoritesMatches.size();
    favoriteMatches.add(matchId);
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(changedPosition);
}
else {
    changedPosition = favoriteMatches.indexOf(matchId); // might not work
    favoriteMatches.remove(matchId);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(changedPosition);
}
```

Or, instead update the entire list

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Read more about [notifying the adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView#notifying-the-adapter), but note

> a RecyclerView adapter should not rely on `notifyDataSetChanged()` since the more granular actions should be used.